# How to do payment through UPI in react native

Tags: react-native, upi

I have been trying to integrate upi payment in react native using react-native-upi

```
const initPayment = () => {
    try {
      RNUpiPayment.initializePayment(
      {
        vpa: '#xxxxxxxxxx', // or can be john@ybl or mobileNo@upi
        payeeName: 'User',
        amount: '1',
        transactionNote: 'Transaction Note',
        transactionRef: '#xxxxxxxxxxx',
      },
      successCallback,
      failureCallback,
     );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


function successCallback(data) {
    try {
      console.log('Success');
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }


function failureCallback(data) {
    try {
      console.log('Failed');
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

But I am getting error: `You have exceeded the maximum transaction amount set by your bank`.

I have tried this using different merchant IDs but I am getting this same error.

I have tried different packages too, but not able to do upi payment

If somebody has a solution for this, or knows any different approach then please help me, I have been stuck on this since last 20 days.